I'm trying to save a graph on gnuplot windows, but it doesnt create a file, what's wrong in it?
A new window with the graph is created and i can save a file from the window, but i wanted to know if this set of commands should've created a file with the graph or i should save manually and, if it should save, whats the path/where does it save my graph or where do i see the path in which the graph is saved. It's really the most basic file saving that somehow i am still lost and dont know how to do, even by doing the exact commands of the manual.
I'm trying to learn gnuplot and just installed. I've been testing in the wgnuplot (the one that was created on the desktop) by using the normal commands:
Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> plot sin(x) 
gnuplot> set terminal pdf

Terminal type is now 'pdfcairo'
Options are ' transparent enhanced fontscale 0.5 size 5.00in, 3.00in '
gnuplot> set output "testsin.pdf"
gnuplot> replot
gnuplot> unset output
gnuplot> unset terminal

it cant find if it creates a file with the output

Yes, it should create the file in the current working directory.

As choroba already mentioned in the comments, if you don't give an explicit path, the  output file will be created in the current working directory.
Check help pwd.
Type pwd and it will print the current working directory.
Also check help cd, i.e. change the working directory.
Besides absolute paths, e.g.
set output 'C:\Users\Test\Scripts\Dir\SubDir\myOutput.pdf'

you can also give relative paths, e.g.
set output 'Dir\SubDir\myOutput.pdf'

As suggested under help cd, for Windows you better use single quotes. Or you could also use foreslashes as in Linux.
What I typically do is creating a shortcut for wgnuplot.exe and enter my preferred working directory in "Starting in:".


thanks! it was saving my files on a random documents paste, but i found it now

It's probably in the gnuplot program directory
